# Calculating an expectation given the mgf

Tags: probability, expectation

[image]

Hi all, having a bit of difficulty being able to solve the problem above.

I know from the mgf that it's a geometric distribution (p = 0.25, q = 0.75) and am able to find its subsequent pmf. However, when I try to find the expectation given, the series I am trying to solve is diverging. Not sure if this is supposed to happen or I am on the wrong track.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming $M(t)$ is the mgf of $X$, i.e. $M(t) = E(e^{tX})$. If so then
$$ E[(1 - 0.75e)e^{X - 1} + 0.75] = \frac{1 - 0.75 e}{e} E[e^X] + 0.75 $$
But $M(1) = \infty$ (the values on which a mgf is finite forms a convex set therefore since it is infinite at $t = - \ln(0.75)$ is can't be finite at $1$).

Comment: That's what I thought, but in the question it specifies that t < -ln(0.75), so I'm assuming I can't plug in M(1) since -ln(0.75) < 1

Comment: Ah, yes you're right. In that case the expectation diverges to infinity since $E[e^X] = \infty$ so your sum should diverge. I've edited the answer now.

Comment: Oh great! Thanks so much for your help, your explanation makes perfect sense :)